# Matlab: Bottom of text from `text()` chopped

Tags: matlab-figure

I am trying to label my bars in a 3D bar graph:

```
clf
yMax = 2;
xMax = 3;
z=floor(10*rand(yMax,xMax));
bar3(z)
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
x = reshape( repmat(1:xMax,yMax,1), [], 1 );
y = repmat( (1:yMax)', xMax,1 );
%htext = text( x, y, z(:), repmat( {'TEST'}, xMax*yMax, 1 ) )
htext = text( x, y, z(:), 'TEST' )
```

No matter how big I make the figure, the text gets chopped at the bottom:

[image]

Can anyone suggest a way to track down the cause, and/or suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fortunate to catch a few minutes with a guru.  The explanation: The `VerticalAlignment` defaults to `middle`, which works fine for 2D plots.  For each of the 3D bars above, however, `middle` means that the middle of the text sits right at the top surface of the box.  Therefore, the bottom half of the text is *inside* the box.  The problem is solved by modifying the `text` command:

```
htext = text( x, y, z(:), 'TEST' , 'VerticalAlignment','Bottom' )
```

Weird how I couldn't find it in a web search, but hopefully, this answer will fix that.